# Can I give someone limited access to an Azure account?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I want to outsource the development of a WordPress website that will be hosted in Azure.  Is there a way to create a Cloud Service that I can give someone access to, but at the same time not giving them my Azure subscription credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an Azure subscription perspective, you can only grant co-admin privilege; a co-admin gets full access to a subscription. This leaves you with a few options (I'm sure you can think of others):

- Set up a separate subscription solely for the outsourced WordPress work. At completion of project, you can choose to remove the co-admin rights of the subscription
- Grant admin access to the WordPress site, along with specific Azure resource keys (e.g. storage account namespace+key; service bus, MySQL credentials, etc.) for your developer to do the work. You can always change access keys once the project is completed
- Have your developer set up WordPress in their own subscription, and then transfer the contents to your subscription when the project is complete.

**EDIT** - I slightly misunderstood the question, and was thinking the outsourced dev needed certain subscription-level resources. As Mike pointed out, source control is a good solution for Web Sites. You'd still need to set up resources such as Storage accounts if you don't want to set them up as co-admin.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions.  Very useful indeed.  I also thought of creating an Azure VM and giving the dev Remote Desktop access.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as an answer.  I hadn't realized how easy it was to do the WordPress install.  Eventually I did that, and just gave the dev admin access to the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloud Services then you could set up [continuous integration between TFS and your cloud service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/).  This would allow you to give the other person their own accounts to your TFS source code.  Thus they check in and trigger the build, and it deploys.  They don't have access.

If you don't have to have Cloud Service then you also have the same option with Windows Azure Web Sites (it's under development so this should be fine to run in even under the free, and bump up if you want to load test, etc.).  With that you can give ftp access only, or also set up TFS or GIT source control integration.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion... I hadn't thought of TFS at all... I'll take a look at that.